# Replace Multiple Words in a string

Tags: python

i have the foll txt:

```
txt = "there was a nr opp rd bldg"
```

and i need to replace them with their correct spellings.. so i made a small replacement dictionary

```
rep = {"rd": "road", "nr": "near","opp":"opposite","bldg":"building"}
```

and used the following code:

```
def replace_all(text, rep):  
    for i, j in rep.iteritems():  
        text = text.replace(i, j)  
    return text 

replace_all(txt,rep)
print txt
```

but the output dint change.. What could be the reason?

Comment: Is that the indentation you are actually using? Looks like the `text.replace` is outside the loop

Comment: This code will have unexpected results. For example, `opposite` will be replaced with `oppositeosite`.

Comment: lol , yeah.. any fix to that??? (oppositeosite)

Comment: Use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). A good start would be to use the expression `r'\b\w+\b'` in conjuction with `re.sub()`.

Comment: Thanks. For those happening on this many years later with Python 3, use *items* not *iteritems* i.e. `for i, j in changeDict.items():`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function `replace_all` changes a local variable `text` and then returns it.

Your mistake is not assigning the returned value into the global variable `txt`.

Use `txt = replace_all(txt,rep)`, and it should solve your problem.

Comment: The idea behind this is that strings are immutable in python, meaning that operations on strings don't change the string object, but create a different string object, a copy if you will..

Comment: Thanks; answer revised in order to explain to OP why he/she needs to add `txt = ...`.